# Problem with upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 16.10

[image]

I'm trying to upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 but it took too much time (about 2 hours) with no feedback.

Is this expected or is there a problem?

Comment: The [Canocical Group Ltd.] (https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) download site appears to be running normally from here at the moment. Have you checked your Network and DNS configuration recently?

Comment: @ThompsonDawes Updates/upgrades are downloaded from the repositories mirrors, usually one from the same country. The local mirror can be slow, in maintenance or even temporarily down. But that's not even the case here, the packages were already downloaded. It's stalling at "Installing the upgrades" and that may well be because it's waiting for user input.

Comment: @CelticWarrior a good point. It seems like Khaled is going to need to take a closer look to determine what, and where, that Package configuration is hanging up, perhapses by selecting an alternate repository mirror, or updating his lookup tables. What ever does the trick. Reboot and try again?

Comment: i'm sorry it just asked me to press enter hahaha